# Yii framework: CPhpAuthManager error

Tags: php, yii, rbac, yii-validation

I try to make a RBAC with this  [guide](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/65/how-to-setup-rbac-with-a-php-file/)
I made it work without errors so far, but i got stuck now for a few hours, cause the rules in my model just wont work. I try to test the reader role with this code:

```
<?php if(Yii::app()->user->checkAccess('reader')): ?>
<h1> Grats u are a reader </h1>

<?php endif; ?>
```

So after i log in this litle message should appear but somehow it wont. And for example when i log in and try to go to my models index, so i can see the registered users it is telling me that i dont have the permission, even thought i did this:

```
         array('allow',  // allow all users to perform 'index' and 'view' actions
            'actions'=>array('view','index'),
            'roles'=>array('reader')

        ),
```

Any idea is welcome, and tell me if i have to show some more code. Ok back to thinking.

Comment: Check that the tables are created in the database and there exists at least one entry with the userid you're logged in, and the role 'reader' assigned.

Comment: yes it is assigned. Now the problem is, with the reader role i can do anything i want, but with the same actions on the admin role, i cant do anything.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it. Just had to give straight accessRules. Like the reader can go to index , and view page, but cant do to update , and admin, and the inverse of this for the admin role.